# no "charset_map" between the charsets "utf-8" and "iso-8859-1" while reading response header from upstream

Tags: internationalization, nginx-config, error-log, google-search-console

i need really iso-8859-1 (german charset latin-1) for JTL Shop 4 (german produkt, it can't use today UTF-8)

in my additional nginx configuration i set up.

```
override_charset on;
charset iso-8859-1;
```

than i receive in the proxy_log nginx log, this error message

no "charset_map" between the charsets "utf-8" and "iso-8859-1" while reading response header from upstream

than it doesn't work corretly with the google search bot. on the Frontend everything is ok, but google search / google Webmaster Tools i can see that it doesn't index the correct words for äöüß and other special chars.

i think this error message is part of the error for the google search bot